# Add input of text file in map with struct c++

Tags: c++, collections, enums, mapping, ifstream

This is the content of my text file, separated with tabs:

```
_fLetters   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   
_lLetters   H   I   J   K   L   M   N   O
```

`_fLetters` and `_lletters` should be the keys of the `map`.

Now I have the following `struct`, `enum`, and `map`:

```
struct Letters
{
  std::string AS;
  std::string BS;

  Letters(std::string AS, std::string BS) : AS(AS), BS(BS) { };
  bool operator<(const Letters& key) const { return AS < key.AS || (AS == key.AS && BS < key.BS); };
};

enum e{
  English = 0,
  Deutsch = 1,
  NumberOfLanguages = 2
};

static std::map<Letters, const std::array<std::string, NumberOfLanguages>> mapTexts;

std::array<std::string, NumberOfLanguages> Texts;


int main()
{
  std::ifstream file("letters.txt");
  std::string content;

  while (file >> content) {

  }
  return 0;

}
```

How can I read the input of this text file line-by-line separated by tabs into my map?

Comment: `while (file >> content)` won't do it. That reads **a** (singular) whitespace/eos delimited string. You need `std::getline` for line-by-line consumption from your file. From there, choose whatever mechanism you want for splitting the line-string up and extracting your member fields.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, i know thats not how it works, but can you help me with this while loop?

Comment: @RemyLebeau oh okay, thank you could you write this as code? would be great to understand better

Comment: There is a good example of using `std:;getline` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). You'll also find documentation and examples on `std::istringstream` there as well.

Comment: @WhozCraig thank you, i understand, but i think my main problem is how to deal with the map, especially with adding the key and the struct.

Comment: @SIMCHE You do realize that your `map` is `const`, don't you? So you can't add anything to it after it has been initialized.

Comment: @RemyLebeau oh, yes thats true, how would you deal with it if its not const?

Comment: @SIMCHE kind of hard to answer that when you haven't explained how the file text correlates to your `map` structure to begin with. For instance, why does `Letters` have 2 `string`s in it, why do you want to store an array of 2 `string`s for each `Letter`, and what is the purpose of `enum e`? Your code is more complex than your question warrants, so please simplify the issue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau the input of the text file i posted is not everything, i want to add to every entry a language. Later there might be entries like, "House, garden, car" -> english, and "haus, garten, auto" -> german

Comment: @SIMCHE your question is about how to read the file data into the `map`, the rest is irrelevant. So, what do you want the `map` to look like when each entry in the file has been added to it?

Comment: @RemyLebeau it should look like
key -> _fLetters
then {A,B,C...
and at the end the number of the languages, thats everything

Comment: Your map's key type is a class named `Letters` which contains 2 `string`s. How do you expect to create that from a single `string` like `"_fLetters"` or `"_lLetters"`? And the map's value type is an array of 2 `string`s, so how do you expect to store the letters of each line into that array? You are not offering any useful details about your situation or your desired result.  I'm sorry, but unless you do, I'm out. I've already provided my answer to the actual question asked (how to read the file), the rest is on you to figure out. Good luck.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246257/discussion-between-simche-and-remy-lebeau).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`std::getline()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) instead of `operator>>` in your outer loop. Then you can use [`std::istringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) to parse each line as needed.

For example:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
  std::ifstream file("letters.txt");
  std::string line, key;
  char letter;

  std::map<std::string, std::string> textMap;

  while (std::getline(file, line)) {
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    iss >> key;
    while (iss >> letter) {
      textMap[key] += letter;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Once you can extract the `key` and `letter`s of each line, you can do whatever you want with them.  Play around and see how you can apply those values to the `map` structure you want.

Comment: okay thank you, do you know how to set _fletter as key in the map?

Comment: @SIMCHE Have you even read the documentation for [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) yet?

Comment: yeah, i did....

Comment: And? It explains how to add keys/values to a `map`, so what exactly about that is not clear to you?

Comment: it is not clear how to deal with the enum, and first entry as key, could you write these to points as code? it would help me a lot

Comment: "*it is not clear how to deal with the enum*" - It is not clear how YOU are using the enum to begin with, so how do you expect anyone to tell you how to apply it to your map?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246249/discussion-between-simche-and-remy-lebeau).